# C++. Узнать дату изменения значения реестра

Tags: c++, реестр, wmi

Нужно программно узнать когда последний раз менялось значение (именно значение, а не ключ) в реестре. В интернете кроме как [RegistryValueChangeEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) ничего не нашел. Но и нормальный пример WMI запроса, который выдаст дату изменения параметра я не нашел. Самому тоже не получилось написть.
Если кто знает как на C++ программно решить мою проблему, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, узнать, когда значение менялось в последний раз, даже если при этом _ваша программа не была запущена_?

Comment: Да, именно это мне и нужно. По факту, моя программа и будет запускаться просто для того, что бы проверить, когда менялось значение.

Comment: я думаю надо копать в строну аудита реестра. только вот придется в аудит все ключи добавить.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, аудит рессетра подразумивает какие-то настройки на машине, на которой будет запускаться мое приложение. К сожалению, такой возможности нет.

Comment: тогда остается только периодически сканировать файл реестра и выяснять что в нем изменилось.

Comment: может вам чемто вот эта статейка поможет? http://citforum.ru/operating_systems/windows/registry_c/

Comment: perfect, этот вариант не подходит. Суть такова, что при подключении на сервер на клиенте проверяется дата изменения определенного значения реестра.Затем сервер обрабатывает эту дату ну и делает определенные выводы на счет этого клиента.

Comment: с таким условием все упрощается. засекаем значение ключа (раз ключ известен) до подключения клиента, потом ждем отключение клиента и проверяем изменилось ли значения ключа. а датой будет время отключение клиента.

Comment: Клиентское приложение не работает в фоне на клиентской машине. Оно запускается на клиенте в произвольные моменты времени, поэтому получить значение до подключения к серверу и мониторить его после отключения - не получится.

Comment: тогда временем будет запуск вашей программы. без мониторинга никак. реестр не порождает никаких сигналов как и любая другая база данных, а время изменения ключа никуда не записывается(ну по крайней мере мои знания таковы на текущий момент).

Comment: @rudolfninja , лутше чем вот это вы ничего не сделаете https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RegMon

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, в RegMon идет перехват функций по работе с реестром и логируется информация об их вызове. Все выглядит так, как будто нет подходящего решения проблемы. Спасибо всем за попытку помочь.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял задачу, вам требуется проверить, что поменялось конкретное значение в *любом* ключе, т.е. путь к ключу (ключам) вы не знаете или они случайные

Сначала в целом:

Реестр есть виртуальная файловая система и/или база данных (смотря как на него смотреть). Вся информация о ключе есть мета-данных этого ключа. Мета-данные можно запросить методом [RegQueryInfoKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724902(v=vs.85).aspx)

Там есть поле, которое позволяет выяснить время последней *записи* в ключ

> lpftLastWriteTime [out, optional]
>
> A pointer to a FILETIME structure that receives the last write time. This parameter can be NULL.
>
> The function sets the members of the FILETIME structure to indicate the last time that the key or any of its value entries is
>   modified.

Было ли в ключ записано значение отличное от предыдущего или нет история реестра умалчивает. Такой информации там не хранится и, насколько мне известно, никаких проверок на идентичность записанной информации записываемой реестр не делает

Теперь про задачу:

Если сохранить timestamp всех ключей с нужным типом (и исключить явно системные пути вроде регистра классов), где значение может быть, то при повторном подключении можно достаточно быстро проверить, какие ключи поменялись - при изменении ключа меняется дата не только самого ключа, но и всех его предков. Т.е. если у "папки" реестра дата не изменилась - дальше можно не проверять

Но тут надо помнить, что реестр это просто файл и его всегда можно изменить не меняя мета-данных или откатить изменения не оставив следа. Так что если вы планируете это как какую-то защиту (иначе я не понимаю почему вы не знаете пути), то это врядли сработает.

Comment: Задача не совсем такая. Основная суть задачи в том, что когда клиент коннектится на сервер, он должен отправить серверу дату последнего полного скана MSE. HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Scan содержит значениеLastFullScanID. Это значение меняется после каждого полного скана и самому поменять это значение нельзя, оно находится под какой-то защитой MSE.Чтобы получить нужную дату я думал просто посмотреть когда поменялось это значение - это и есть нужная дата. Это единственное решение задачи, которое я придумал (Event viewer не подходит)

Comment: В таком случае достаточно просто посмотреть последнее время записи. Но поменять реестр "ручками" можно всегда - банально извне заменить/отредактировать файл

Comment: Так какой смысл смотреть последнее время записи если в ключе Scan кроме LastFullScanID находится еще много других значений? Мне же нужно получить время последнего изменения определенного значения (LastFullScanID), а не всего ключа. Этот ключ находится под каким-то селф-протекшеном, и поменять его ручками через редактор реестра не выходит.

Comment: Реестр оперирует ключами. То что каждый ключ это словарь значений - это так, приятный бонус. Максимум гранулярности мета-данных, что вы можете получить - это мета-информация по ключам.

P.S. Иными словами это означает, что вы можете получить верхнюю оценку времени, но не само время.